# Why does my code output incorrect results? Integer overflow?

Tags: c++, arrays, codeblocks

Assume that we have 15 numbers from a[0] to a[14] that satisfy:

```
a[0]=4
a[i]=pow(sqrt(a[i-1])*2-1, 2) for i>=1 and i<=14
```

**I need to print out all the values from a[0] to a[14], each number is on one line**, so I write the following code (C++, Code::Blocks):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
#define maxN 15
int i[maxN]; int n=15;
int main()
{
    i[0]=2;
    cout<<4<<endl;
    for (int k=1; k<n; k++){
        i[k]=i[k-1]*2-1;
        cout<<pow(i[k],2)<<"\t"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The result is:

```
4
9
25
81
289
1089
4225
16641
66049
263169
1.05062e+006
4.1984e+006
1.67854e+007
6.71252e+007
2.68468e+008
```

The last five numbers are not correct (because of integer overflow).

In the "for" loop above, I change the line

```
cout<<pow(i[k],2)<<"\t"<<endl;
```

to

```
cout<<(long) pow(i[k],2)<<"\t"<<endl;
```

This time, the result is:

```
4
9
24
81
289
1089
4224
16641
66048
263168
1050625
4198400
16785408
67125248
268468224
```

After I checked manually, I realized that many numbers are still incorrect: 24; 4224; 66048; 263168; 4198400; 16785408; 67125248; 268468224 (they are all 1 lower than the correct numbers). What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Your for loop is different than your `a[i]` definition.

Comment: *What should I do to fix this?* The `pow` function is a floating point function.  Floating point in computers is not like algebra in school, as floating point does not guarantee "exact math".  [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What should I do to fix this?

change

```
cout<<pow(i[k],2)<<"\t"<<endl;
```

to

```
cout<<i[k]*i[k]<<"\t"<<endl;
```

`pow` is a floating point function, which can be imprecise. Note, that in your case there is something strange: if `pow` uses 64-bit IEEE-754 doubles, it should print accurate numbers for your input. So maybe you use 32-bit `float` numbers.

Answer (score 8):

1.05062e+006 and 1050625 are the same values, printed differently. [`pow(i[k],2)` returns a floating point type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow), no integer overflow takes place here, but rather rounding when you convert such a floating point to `long`.

The format `Xe+Y` is called *scientific notation*, its value is `X * 10 ^ Y`. By default, `std::printf` and `std::ostream::operator<<` prints floating points values exceeding a certain bound in their scientific notation. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed for more info.